# Refresh Materialized View produces ERROR: could not create unique index

Tags: postgresql

I have a materialized view `my_view` which selects values from different tables.

I inserted few rows to one of the table and tried to refresh `my_view` by running query

`refresh materialized view my_view;`

But got the below error

```
ERROR:  could not create unique index "my_view_id_idx"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(20477871) is duplicated.
SQL state: 23505
```

So I deleted the rows from the table and refreshed the view again. It still shows the same error. I'm sure that there no duplicate rows in the table and I have deleted the rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

You must have forgotten a row or three.

Try this query to test:

```
SELECT id, count(*)
FROM (/* materialized view definition query */) AS q
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

That will show you the problem `id`s.

Comment: Thanks! I could see some duplicate ids. Is there a way to delete those rows

Comment: Yes: find out the `ctid` (unique physical address) of the rows you want to delete and delete by `ctid`. There are very many questions about "removing duplicate rows" on Stackoverflow, as this is a favorite pastime among those who spurn primary key constraints.